# Trying to flash Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I keep getting this error after I run `phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b`

```
ERROR:phablet-flash:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/dom/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130808.lock'
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The latest **phablet-flash** tool update creates way too many zero length lock files.

---

For each build directory in **Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/**, type the following:

**`touch Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/<build-date>.lock`**

eg. (for your example)

**`touch Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130808.lock`**

Note: *This should not reoccur for any future downloads.*